# Javascript syntax-highlight for JsDoc comments

Tags: syntax-highlighting, comments, filetype-javascript

I now use plugin [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) just to have a nice syntax highlight for [JsDoc](https://jsdoc.app/) comments in my Javascript files.

[vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) provides nice colors highlight but it conflict with all  parentheses highlighters plugins I tried, like nice [rainbow](https://github.com/luochen1990/rainbow).

So I want to dismiss [vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) that seems the cause of conflict.

Question:
there is any vim stand-alone plugin to just do JsDoc syntax highlight (substituting vim-javascript highlighting) that doesn't conflict with parentheses highlighters?